# How long should I wait for acceptance to enact a change on a smaller Beta community?

Tags: discussion, meta, beta-sites

I occasionally get a bit enthusiastic and jog on over to one of the SE Betas to propose changes to minor things that don't quite smell right (generally re-tagging, or tag-synonymizing (the proposal restrictions to which, I detest), for example).

Generally, I try to ask the Beta Meta whether a change should be made, but I have jumped the gun on occasion (and have no problem reverting if requested to).  Other times, I wait, **but for how long?  And how much positive feedback should I wait for before enacting a change?**   I'd say we have about 3-4 really "active" people doing the work there, but since it's a slow-paced SE community, "active" doesn't necessarily mean "present", and let's get real : I don't expect unpaid moderators to check in or answer every meta question.

Good feedback (4 upvotes, comments by 3+ people) sometimes takes a few weeks.  Sometimes I might have already taken action due to my own impatience and excitement.

In general, how long should one be patient for?

Comment: You can't really generalize this; it's going to vary based on the specifics of both the community and the action in question.

Comment: @servy - Well, I thought it might be a bit general when asked, which is why I threw it here.  One might suspect that there is a grouping of generic questions that should be default-asked on each individual meta.

Answer (score 4):

To me there is no hard and fast "rule" as to how long to wait and I have been through one Beta (now a much larger site) and am currently in another.

In general, if I have an idea for how to improve a site I bring it up on its Meta then:

- if all I get is agreement, I may start to implement within a few days
- if all I get is silence, I may start to implement after a week or two
- if I get some disagreement, mixed with support, I re-phrase my idea, and watch to see whether general consensus emerges before implementing (or abandoning)
- if I get strong disagreement and no support then I re-think my idea (and probably abandon it)